# how to close dropdown with hover animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have this code for the navbar dropdown animation. How you can see it works with hover.
The problem is on the phone, I can open the dropdown but i can't close it.

How can I change the code that it works on the phone too?

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".dropdown").hover(            
                function() {
                    $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop( true, true ).slideDown("fast");
                    $(this).toggleClass('open');        
                },
                function() {
                    $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop( true, true ).slideUp("fast");
                    $(this).toggleClass('open');       
                }
            );
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use click event for Handel in mobile

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

$(document).on("click ", function(e) {
    var container = $(".dropdown-menu");

    // if the target of the click is the container
    if (container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length > 0) {
        container.hide();
    }
});

} else {

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown").hover(
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        }
    );
});
}
```

I change my code to check mobile.

Comment: is it possible, to change my code with like an "if" that detects if its mobile or pc?

Comment: thank you very much. It works.   and that its perfectly, is it possible that the animations slideup and down works on the phone too?

Comment: @UdisKlorenz your welcome, yes you can use slideUp() and slideDown() method instead of hide(), or use toggleClass() base on your code

Comment: hei @SadeqHatami
Your code works but I found one error when I tested it on an iPad. it doesn't see that's an iPad and so I can not close the dropdown...
How can i solve that?